# Serialization throws InvalidClassExceptionn

Tags: java, exception, serialization

I'm new serialization (and programming in general) so i don't really know what happens under the hood. I'm making an email client program and the class
`FileHandlerObject` is used to write and read email messages that i send. I maintain an ArrayList and it is read, updated with new email and then written again. I don't understand why it throws an `InvalidClassException` because the file contains an `ArrayList` so the casting should be no problem.
I'm maintaining an `ArrayList` because the `writeObject()` truncates the file every time it writes.(Let me know if im wrong here)

```
class FileHandlerObject implements MyFileHandler<EmailMessage>{

public void write(EmailMessage input){
    try
    {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream("emails.ser");
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream=new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<EmailMessage> messagelist= (ArrayList<EmailMessage>) objectInputStream.readObject();
    objectInputStream.close();
    
    messagelist.add(input);
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("emails.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(messagelist);
    objectOutputStream.flush();
    objectOutputStream.close();
    }
    
    catch(FileNotFoundException f)
    {
        try{
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("emails.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            ArrayList<EmailMessage> messagelist=new ArrayList<EmailMessage>();
            messagelist.add(input);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(messagelist);
            objectOutputStream.flush();
            objectOutputStream.close();

        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}

public ArrayList<EmailMessage> read(){
    
   
    try{
        FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream("emails.ser");
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream=new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<EmailMessage> messagelist= (ArrayList<EmailMessage>) objectInputStream.readObject();
        objectInputStream.close();

        return messagelist;
        
    
    }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
        {
            c.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassCastException c) 
        {
            c.printStackTrace();
        }

        

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Complete error message and stack trace please. There is information in there, believe it or not.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! The reason your question is being downvoted is because you don't include the full error message, making it difficult to help you. Please include the full error message to avoid downvotes and potential question closure. Also please read [*How to Ask*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InvalidClassException.html) explain, this means one of a few things. The code you pasted does not give any insights about which of these mistakes you've made.

- You saved some emails. Then, you edited the `EmailMessage` class, for example by adding a method or changing the name of a field, and then you ran the code again which ends up reading that file that was 'saved' with an *old* version of `EmailMessage` and which you are now trying to read with a *new* version. The java serialization mechanism can theoretically deal with versioning schemes but in practice it's a disaster. Ditch serialization, write your own protocol instead.
- The `EmailMessage` class does not implement `Serializable` and does not have a no-args constructor. Give it a no-args constructor, and add `implements Serializable` to it.
- Your classpath is incomplete; EmailMessage contains fields or methods that refer to some other class you wrote and it is not available on the classpath right now. Fix your classpath.